# Mortgage Calculator Math

Tags: math, calculator

I am trying to construct a mortgage calculator app but my numbers are off a bit and I am wondering if anyone has any insight into what I am missing. The initial payment amount seems to be accurate but as you increase the year and interest rate the value is slightly off. This is for Canada if that makes any difference. The payment amount also doesn't divide evenly into the amount borrowed either. Here is the relevant code.

```
double r = interestAmountValue/1200;

double n = yearAmountValue * 12;
double rPower = pow(1+r, n);
double paymentAmt = loanAmountValue * r * rPower / (rPower - 1);

double totalPaymentd = paymentAmt * n;
double totalInterestd = totalPaymentd - loanAmountValue;
```

Comment: So `r` is the monthly interest rate, `n` is the amount paid for one year, `yearAmountValue` is the number of months, and `paymentAmt` is the monthly payment?  Some more descriptive variable names may help.  What values have you been trying that are giving values that are off?

Comment: 1,000,000 for loanAmountValue , 30 for yearAmountValue & 8.00% for interestAmountValue

Comment: paymentAmt is the real issue here not total payment - for instance with  the numbers i just provided you the total payment amount would be 7337.65 - which $90.53 more than what it should be when i enter those amounts into Canadian mortgage calculators

Comment: also i should note that this is an app with sliders - when my initial values are 10,000 - 1 year - 1% the monthly payment amount is correct, only when these values get scaled higher does the number become less accurate

Comment: What mortgage calculators are you using, and where did you get your formulas?

Comment: http://www.tdcanadatrust.com/docs/mortCalc/MortgageCalculator.jsp

Comment: http://easyiphonedevelopment.blogspot.ca/2010/07/implementing-easy-loan-calculator.html - for the formula

Answer (score 0):

The type `double` is typically implemented as a floating point number. Although calculations using floating points can be fast, particularly when using dedicated hardware, [the tradeoff is accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). This is a well documented problem: see volume II of *The Art of Computer Programming: Semi-Numerical Algorithms* for a thorough discussion.

If provided by your language, an arbitrary precision number type will probably result in better accuracy at the expense of some speed (with the loss of speed probably unnoticeable in most applications on modern hardware for typical problems). In Java this is the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) type.

Comment: What would this be for objective-c?

Comment: I do not know objective-c.

Comment: It's hard to tell without OP giving actual numbers, but this feels more like wrong formulas than floating point errors.

Comment: @Teepeemm `(.1  + .2) * 1000 =  300.00000000000006` Floating point issues could become manifest in fairly mundane circumstances. That's why they are inappropriate in financial settings.